# How to debug an OSGi Bundle inside eclipse using maven structured project

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, osgi

I have a maven project which library should also be an OSGi bundle with an
declarative service. I added the OSGI-INF folder with the service.xml inside
src/java/resources which will be added to the jar. But: When I start the project as equinox project, where I want to check if the service is loaded, I get the error that the OSGI-INF/service.xml can't be found. I guess eclipse won't add the resources folder to the classpath when starting.

BTW: The MANIFEST-MF is in the root folder and the pom.xml contains the following text:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifestFile>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Has anbody a good idea how to tell eclipse where to find the metadata files? I'm using m2eclipse if this is relevant.

Thanks in advance
Hannes

Answer (score 2):

I've the same issues but I've manually tweaked my POM.xml for copying the generate target/classes/META-INF/** stuff (MANIFEST.MF, property files, spring XMLs, ...) into the project ROOT folder (which Eclipse PDE expects):

```
            <!--
            We copy all stuff from target/classes/META-INF into META-INF/ in order 
            to keep Maven output with PDE.
         -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>synch-pde-metadata-from-maven</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/META-INF</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>target/classes/META-INF</directory>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!--
            We delete all stuff from the root bundle's META-INF 
         -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>META-INF</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

(I also clean up things when mvn clean is called) It is not really efficient but it works.

Ps: you may have to right-click on the project and make it a plug-in project in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that Eclipse needs that OSGI-INF (and also META-INF) Folder in root.

I have found a link on how to probably solve the problem.
https://www.nuxeo.com/blog/working-with-osgi-and-maven-in-eclipse/

Basically they put the OSGI-INF and META-INF Folders into src/main/resources

Then they set the src/main/resources Folder as root of the OSGI project. So that Eclipse has both Folders at root.
To have Soure Files also available they added a [Linked Resources](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_linked.htm) to src/main/java by adding an entry to the .project File

```
 <linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>src</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/java</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

Now you just need to copy the .prject and .classpath Files into src/main/resources (your new root) and everything should be working.

By the time of this writing i didn't test this on my own but will do so in the near future.