# How to add Maven Dependencies to my OSGi Bundle Plug-in Dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, osgi-bundle

Im building a e(fx)clipse application. e(fx)clipse is based on equinox for his osgi bundle. I created now a bundle and into his pom.xml i have this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
<artifactId>shiro-guice</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In my plug-in(bundle) i want to imported the shiro bundle [image: here] but i cant! Because the maven dependencies cannot be detected by the eclipse osgi framework as plugin.

How can i automatically add my Maven Dependencies into my Manifest Path so that i can imported it into my bundle?

Answer (score 0):

goto windows-preference-maven and check download repository index update on startup and restart it to take place..

if u have comitted broken downloads remove them by

```
find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
```

and if both wont work [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4293042/2906949)